# iOS SpriteKit split screen for lazy eye exercise

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, google-cardboard, durovis-dive

## A Little Background

My son Seth has a Lazy Eye and there is evidence that his condition can be improved by playing video games. 
[Tetris Video Game Helps Treat Lazy Eye](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/259547.php)

Basically he has poor focus in one eye and perfect focus in the other eye. Over time his brain has started the process of shutting off and ignoring the bad eye. He wears a contact now to correct the focus issue but, his brain is still in the habit of ignoring that eye.

So not just any game will work. He needs something that forces his eyes to collaborate to bring together and track images.

I can use [Durovis Dive](http://www.durovis.com/opendive-howto.html) or [Google Cardboard](https://cardboard.withgoogle.com/) to separate the images he will be processing.

He is a fan of Flappy Bird so a clone of this would be a good start.

My thought is to have the bird visible only to his left eye and the pipes only visible to his right eye. The background is visible to both eyes to give his brain a reference to bring the images together.

## So Here is the actual question

I have ran into an issue trying to get a scrolling background and scrolling pipes working in two screens that clip at the right point.

#### How can I create a screen like below that

1. **The background scrolls in sync in both windows?**
2. **The pipes clip at the center?**

[image]

**Thanks!**

Comment: A crop node (or two) might do the trick so that it masks out the other half of the screen.

Comment: I did try using a crop node. Maybe I gave up too soon I will give it another shot.

Comment: I tried again and the crop node to work but it is painfully slow in the emulator. my FPS dropped from 30 to 20 when I added the first crop node. it dropped from 20 to 12 when I added the second one.

Comment: The simulator is slow for anything graphical. Test it on a device.

Comment: Yep lots faster on the device. Thanks! So it took 2 crop nodes one for each side of the screen. If you wanna make that an answer instead of a comment I can give you credit.

Comment: this looks like a great project did you get somewhere with it ?

Comment: I did get it working with a crop screen, but i never took the project to done, done, I need to revisit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crop node (or two) might do the trick so that it masks out the other half of the screen.